# Project in SonarQube is missing

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

**Old way**

Earlier, I checked a C# project in SonarQube the "old" way: Created a file called `sonar-project.properties` and ran Sonar-runner on it. This was with SonarQube 5.6 LTS. There were no problems.

With the old way, my project had in `sonar-project.properties` a project key  like `project:trunk` and a project name like `Project Name`

**New way**

Some weeks ago, I upgraded to SonarQube 6.7.1. LTS. With this, I also changed the way the project is checked. Now I first call `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild begin`, then I compile my project, and then I call `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild end`. This part seems to work fine.

When calling `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild`, I give him a parameter `/n:"Project Name"`. As far as I know, there is no parameter for the project key.

**My problem**

But now here is my problem: From time to time, my project, which is checked by the new way, is not listed in the list of projects on http://sonarqube-server:9000/projects 
Some times I can see that project, but then it vanishes and I need to start the checking again to see it on the sonarqube-server.

Does anyone know why is that?

**EDIT**

Additionally, I post here the output of `logs/web.log` of all lines with `ERROR` and `WARN`

```
2018.01.19 11:50:16 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed: Found two files for the same plugin [php]: sonar-php-plugin-2.12.0.2871.jar and sonar-php-plugin-2.9.2.1744.jar
2018.01.19 11:52:33 ERROR web[][abap] No license for abap
2018.01.19 11:52:33 ERROR web[][swift] No license for swift

2018.01.19 11:52:33 WARN  web[][o.s.s.u.DeprecatedViews] Widget 'Sonargraph Structural Debt Dashbox' (sonargraph.structural_debt) is ignored. See org.sonar.api.web.page.PageDefinition to define pages.
2018.01.19 11:52:33 WARN  web[][o.s.s.u.DeprecatedViews] Widget 'Sonargraph Structure Dashbox' (sonargraph.structure) is ignored. See org.sonar.api.web.page.PageDefinition to define pages.
2018.01.19 11:52:33 WARN  web[][o.s.s.u.DeprecatedViews] Widget 'Sonargraph Architecture Dashbox' (sonargraph.architecture) is ignored. See org.sonar.api.web.page.PageDefinition to define pages.
2018.01.19 11:52:33 WARN  web[][o.s.s.u.DeprecatedViews] Widget 'Sonargraph Integration Architecture' (sonargraphintegration_architecture) is ignored. See org.sonar.api.web.page.PageDefinition to define pages.
2018.01.19 11:52:33 WARN  web[][o.s.s.u.DeprecatedViews] Widget 'Sonargraph Integration Structure' (sonargraphintegration_structure) is ignored. See org.sonar.api.web.page.PageDefinition to define pages.
2018.01.19 11:52:33 WARN  web[][o.s.s.u.DeprecatedViews] Widget 'Sonargraph Integration Structural Debt' (sonargraphintegration_structural_debt) is ignored. See org.sonar.api.web.page.PageDefinition to define pages.
```

You can ignore the `ERROR` line with the two `sonar-php-plugin`: I already removed the one with the version `2.9.2.1744` some days ago.

Comment: Could you please have a look in server's log (logs/web.log) and search for some lines starting with ERROR or WARN ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam: See the edit in my initial question.

Comment: You can specify key: `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:my-key`. Not sure if that's the reason for your problem, but I would recommend using it in addition to `/n`

Answer (score 1):

After the comment of Valeri I noticed, that two of my projects used the same key when running `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild`. That's the reason why the project disappeared.